# Script to create heading

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document created by DOORS where the headings in a table are written as "1", "1.1", "2.2.3" etc. (see figure).

[Word table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZtHw.png)

Is there a way to write a macro or vba script to search for cells starting with a number in a given column and delete the number and apply one of the Styles for the line?
For example:

- exchange "1 " and "2 " with "Heading 1" from Style selection
- exchange "1.1 " and "2.3 " with "Heading 2" from Style selection
- exchange "1.1.3 " and "2.3.4 " with "Heading 3" from Style selection
- etc.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Klaus

Answer (score 0):

I used all afternoon solving the problem, and now it works :-)

The code could must likely be prettier, but it works.
Just in case someone else needs this functionality.

Sub ApplyHeadingStyles()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim tCell As Cell
Dim r As Integer

```
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        Set tCell = tbl.Cell(r, 3) ' check only row 3
        If tCell.Range.Text Like "#.#.#.#.#.#*" Then ' search for heading number consisting of x.x.x.x.x.x
            tCell.Range.Text = Right(tCell.Range.Text, Len(tCell.Range.Text) - 12) ' remove old heading numbers
            tCell.Range.Text = Replace(tCell.Range.Text, Chr(13), "") ' remove Carrige Return at end of string
            tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 6")
        End If
    Next r
Next tbl

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        Set tCell = tbl.Cell(r, 3) ' check only row 3
        If tCell.Range.Text Like "#.#.#.#.#*" Then ' search for heading number consisting of x.x.x.x.x
            tCell.Range.Text = Right(tCell.Range.Text, Len(tCell.Range.Text) - 10) ' remove old heading numbers
            tCell.Range.Text = Replace(tCell.Range.Text, Chr(13), "") ' remove Carrige Return at end of string
            tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 5")
        End If
    Next r
Next tbl

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        Set tCell = tbl.Cell(r, 3) ' check only row 3
        If tCell.Range.Text Like "#.#.#.#*" Then ' search for heading number consisting of x.x.x.x
            tCell.Range.Text = Right(tCell.Range.Text, Len(tCell.Range.Text) - 8) ' remove old heading numbers
            tCell.Range.Text = Replace(tCell.Range.Text, Chr(13), "") ' remove Carrige Return at end of string
            tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4")
        End If
    Next r
Next tbl

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        Set tCell = tbl.Cell(r, 3) ' check only row 3
        If tCell.Range.Text Like "#.#.#*" Then ' search for heading number consisting of x.x.x
            tCell.Range.Text = Right(tCell.Range.Text, Len(tCell.Range.Text) - 6) ' remove old heading numbers
            tCell.Range.Text = Replace(tCell.Range.Text, Chr(13), "") ' remove Carrige Return at end of string
            tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")
        End If
    Next r
Next tbl

For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        Set tCell = tbl.Cell(r, 3) ' check only row 3
        If tCell.Range.Text Like "#.#*" Then ' search for heading number consisting of x.x
            tCell.Range.Text = Right(tCell.Range.Text, Len(tCell.Range.Text) - 4) ' remove old heading numbers
            tCell.Range.Text = Replace(tCell.Range.Text, Chr(13), "") ' remove Carrige Return at end of string
            tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
        End If
    Next r
Next tbl
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Brush up of code. Works the same.

Public Function getHeadingNumber(ByRef s As String) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As String

```
If s Like "#.#*" Then ' is it a heading (note: heading 1 are not found)
    i = InStr(s, " ") ' search for first space charater
    ws = Left(s, i) ' keep only digits and bullets in ws
    getHeadingNumber = 1 + Len(ws) - Len(Replace(ws, ".", "")) ' count number of bullets
    
    s = Right(s, Len(s) - i) ' keep only the 12 left most characters
    s = Replace(s, Chr(13), "") ' remove Carrige Return at end of string
Else
    getHeadingNumber = 0 ' not a heading
End If
```

End Function

Sub ApplyHeadingStyles()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim tCell As Cell
Dim r As Integer
Dim heading As Integer
Dim ws As String

```
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        Set tCell = tbl.Cell(r, 3) ' check only row 3
        ws = tCell.Range.Text
        heading = getHeadingNumber(ws)
        If heading > 0 Then
            tCell.Range.Text = ws
            Select Case heading
                Case 1
                    tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
                Case 2
                    tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
                Case 3
                    tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 3")
                Case 4
                    tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 4")
                Case 5
                    tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 5")
                Case 6
                    tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 6")
            End Select
        End If
    Next r
Next tbl

' Set heading in "Test Description"
For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    Set tCell = tbl.Cell(2, 3)
    If tCell.Range.Text Like "1*" Then ' search for heading
        tCell.Range.Text = Right(tCell.Range.Text, Len(tCell.Range.Text) - 2) ' remove old heading numbers
        tCell.Range.Text = Replace(tCell.Range.Text, Chr(13), "") ' remove Carrige Return at end of string
        tCell.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
    End If
Next tbl
```

End Sub